# Generalized sampling with replacement: expected number of duplicates

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I wasn't able to find questions with my generalization, but please point me if this is a duplicate question.

Suppose we have $N$ items, assigned with probability of getting sampled $p_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ where $\sum_i p_i = 1$. Unlike usual sampling with replacement that sample a single item each time, we sample $M$ items without replacement each time. We repeat the sampling process $K$ times with replacement, making total number of sample size $MK$.
Under this process, what is the expected number of items in $k$th sample that we already sampled from the sample $1,\ldots,k-1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  This problem (or at least, the exact solution) might be much more complex than you expect.  In each sampling (of $K$ such), how do you draw $M$ without replacement?  E.g. lets say $N= 3$ and $p = (0.5, 0.3, 0.2)$.  Suppose you first draw the $0.5$ item, and now without replacement, you need to draw a second item.  But the probabilities left are $0.3, 0.2$ and they no longer add to $1$.  The "natural" assumption is you rescale them to $0.6, 0.4$, but just this rescaling step is known to be a difficult problem - because the rescaling factor depends on what you drew before.

Comment: I am far from an expert, but I vaguely recall this being called something like "sampling without replacement with unequal probabilities" perhaps?  A quick google search just now didnt yield much I can understand.  Also, even if the overall setting might be difficult to deal with, you're just asking about an expected value, and for that there might be simpler answers, or at least, good approximations.

Comment: E.g. if we can calculate $q_i = Prob(\text{item $i$ is among the $M$ drawn})$, then the expected value you seek should be $\sum_i q_i (1 - (1 - q_i)^{k-1})$ by linearity of expectation.  But I am not sure how to calculate $q_i$ if you are indeed using the "natural" rescaling model.